# TestNG using Mockito framework

Tags: java

I don't know if this is asked before, but can someone here please explain what is the purpose of using the Mockito framework? I have read a lot of posts online, but I don't see a perfect answer anywhere. My question is, in the TestNG cases where you use Mockito, you first mock all the calls where a function is getting invoked, and lastly invoke the method itself, in which case you are not really improving the processor time etc when you finally invoke the method. How does the framework really help if you still have to make the real call anyway? Apologies if this is a basic question, but I would really appreciate if someone can share how this framework is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito (and other mocking frameworks) all you to stub out the behaviour of components that your class under test needs to interact with.  Consider the following example, in which you have an arbitrary class that sends RESTful HTTP requests using a third party `HttpClient`.

```
public class RestServiceInvoker {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    public RestServiceInvoker(HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public BusinessObject requestResource(String resourceId) {
        HttpResponse response = this.httpClient.sendRequest(
                RequestMethod.GET, "/data/resources/" + resourceId);
        // ... more code goes here to process the response into a BusinessObject ...
        return businessObject;
    }

}
```

Now, in order to unit test `RestServiceInvoker` you, of course, need to construct one, which means providing an implementation of `HttpClient`.  If you use a real HTTP client then you need a web server and some resources for it to retrieve, which is a lot of work, slow to run, and means the scope of your test is far wider than the `RestServiceInvoker` "unit".  It may also make the test unreliable if the test web server becomes unreachable or is slow to respond.

If you use a mock framework, however, you can mock the behaviour of `HttpClient.sendRequest(...)` to assert that it's called with the arguments it expects and also to return an object for you to test the code you're really interested in - in this case, the code that turns an `HttpResponse` into one of your business objects.

You can also set mocks to throw exceptions, which could be useful in this case to test what happens when the network is unavailable, for instance.

So essentially, in this example, the only "real call" you have to make in your TestNG test case would be to `RestServiceInvoker.requestResource(...)`, but thanks to Mockito, you are in control of all the dependencies of your `RestServiceInvoker` and therefore can test-drive your development with confidence.